# Registering a File System in Apache Drill

Tags: filesystems, apache-drill

I'm trying to register a file system in Apache drill but it doesn't work.

I tried these steps:

1. Navigate to http://localhost:8047, and select the Storage tab.
2. In the New Storage Plugin window, enter a unique name and then click Create.
3. In the Configuration window, provide the following configuration information for the type of file system that you are configuring as a data source.a.

I entered:

```
{  "type": "file",  
      "enabled": true,  
      "connection": "file:///",  
      "workspaces": {    
       "root": {      
        "location": "/root/data/json",      
        "writable": false,      
        "storageformat": null    
        }
      },
       "formats" : {      
          "json" : {         
            "type" : "json"      
          }   
      }
  }
```

4. update.

every time when I press the button my code is deleted, Result:
**null**

There is a instance created but without content.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Change `"storageformat": null` to `"defaultInputFormat": null`